# Publish previous, this and next

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm trying to implement previous and next for the current single view. I have the current `id` and search context `slug`. How would I publish and render the current document and links to the previous and next – filtered by the search context and sorted by date? This must be a common problem but I'm having trouble to find an approach that works.

The find `selector` should probably not be the `id` but the date of the current document.

```
Meteor.publish('aPix', function(id, slug) {
    check(id, String);
    if (!slug) {
        slug = 'all';
    }
    // should the selector be the date instead?
    var selector = id;
    // how find this, next and previous documents only?
    return MyPix.find(selector); 
});
```

I have this, but can't find how to implement it. And I'm not sure it's a good approach anyway:

```
var dateOfThisDoc = MyPix.findOne(id).uploadedAt;

var nextDateDoc = MyPix.findOne(
    {uploadedAt: {$gt: dateOfThisDoc}},
    {"metadata.tags": slug}
);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure what your goal is or how your date field works (or what fields you're trying to display from the previous/next records while looking at the current one), but I'll try to answer.

One approach would be to store the key parts of the previous and next documents in each document (sort of a linked list approach).  Then you would only have to publish the current document, and it would bring along with it the couple of data points (perhaps title, for example) from the others that you'd want to show in the client.

That would probably be the most efficient approach from a database access perspective, assuming you're reading more than you're adding/deleting new documents.  It could be more work to maintain than you'd like, though (depending on how and how often new documents are inserted into the middle of the stack).  So if you wanted to stick with the approach above and needed to find the immediately prior and next documents by date, you could do something like:

```
MyPix.find(
  {
    uploadedAt: {$gt: dateOfThisDoc}, 
    "metadata.tags": slug
  },{
    {sort: {dateField: 1}}, 
    limit:1
  }
);
```

to find the next post after the current one and

```
MyPix.find(
  {
    uploadedAt: {$lt: dateOfThisDoc}, 
    "metadata.tags": slug
  },{
    {sort: {dateField: -1}}, 
    limit:1
  }
);
```

for the prior one.

I think you'd need/want separate subscribe/publishes for each of them.

See http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/find and http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/sortspecifiers for more details on the sorting/filtering syntax.

Comment: Thanks! Will be checking this tonight. Regarding writing the next/previous docs into the current document, this would not work for different search contexts – unless the next/previous fields are updated each time a new search is triggered (if I understand you correctly).

Comment: Agreed - if you're trying to show a series of documents that have all been filtered for the search, that definitely wouldn't work.

Comment: In thinking some more, it could be that linking them would make sense, for some use cases.  For example, if the user is likely to want to iterate through most of the documents in any given search.  In that case, it might be worth it to pull the sorted set once and populate the next/prev info for the client, rather than pulling each item as the user iterates through.  The choice of approach would depend on the size of the documents vs the proportion of the search set likely viewed by the user (and thus the # of database filters/sorts/limits that would need to occur with the code above).